# For which whole numbers of variable c does the following LDE have solutions in N?

Tags: number-theory

For which $\mathbb{Z}$ numbers of variable c does the Linear Diophantine Equation $cx + (c + 2)y = c + 4$ have a solution in $\mathbb{N}$ ?

Can please someone explains the whole process?(I know how to solve LDE's in general)

**Addendum:LDE = Linear Diophantine Equation**

Comment: LDE = linear differential equation and $y = y(x)$?

Comment: No.LDE = Linear Diophantine Equation

Comment: It's solvable iff $\gcd(c,c+2)$ is a divisor of $c+4$. But this is always the case, since the gcd on the left is $1$ when $c$ is odd, and $2$ when $c$ is even, in which case $c+4$ is also even.

Comment: Thanks!Just the kind of answer that I've needed!Can you please write this into post so I can accept it as an answer?

Comment: Satoshi... I've made it an answer, including one choice of solution.

Comment: Thanks once again, it's superb!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally these are solvable iff the gcd of the two coefficients divides the right side. Here the gcd of $c,c+2$ is $1$ if $c$ is odd, in which case it automatically divides any right side, and it is $2$ if $c$ is even, in which case one only needs the right side even, which for this problem is $c+4$ so it should work. It isn't hard to tinker around and get explicit solutions...

Let $x=-1,\ y=2$, and then $cx+(c+2)y=c+4.$